# Defining a function that returns one element satisfying the condition

Tags: coq

I want to declare a function that yeilds the element **(b, n)** that the **b** is equal to true.

```
Require Export List.
Import Coq.Lists.List.ListNotations.

Definition lstest := list (bool * nat).


Fixpoint existbool (l : lstest) : option (bool * nat) :=
match l with
| [] => None
| (b, n) :: l' => if b then Some (b, n) else existbool l'
end.
```

The function always get the first element satisfyting **b = true**. I want to express that there exists an element satisfyting **b = true** and returns the element.  How can I define such a function?

Answer (score 0):

In the following function the type of `existbool_ex` tells you that we output a pair contained in the list with its first element true (assuming we output a `Some`).

```
(* These are all from the standard library *)
Locate "{ _ : _ | _ }".
Print sig.
Print In.
Print fst.

(* Defining Property here to shorten code for exist *)
Definition P l (x : bool * nat) := fst x = true /\ In x l.

Fixpoint existbool_ex (l : list (bool * nat)) :
  option {x : bool * nat | fst x = true /\ In x l} :=
  match l return option {x : bool * nat | P l x} with
  | [] => None
  | x' :: l' =>
    match x' with
    | (true,n) as ans =>
      Some (exist (P (ans :: l')) ans (conj eq_refl (or_introl eq_refl)))
    | (false,n) =>
      match existbool_ex l' with
      | None => None
      | Some (exist _ x a) =>
        match a with
        | conj Heq Hin =>
          Some (exist (P ((false, n) :: l')) x (conj Heq (or_intror Hin)))
        end
      end
    end
  end.

(* Note the as pattern got desugared into a let binding. *)
Print existbool_ex.

(* However we have a somewhat sane extraction, (tail recursive) *)
Require Extraction.
Extraction existbool_ex.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function `get_number` that requires a proof that the list has a `true` value somewhere.

```
Definition has_true (l : lstest):= exists n, In (true, n) l.
```

`get_number` is defined with the help of `refine` which lets us leave 'holes' (written `_`) in the proof term to fill in later.  Here we have two holes; one for the absurd case when the list is `[]`, and one where we construct the proof term for the recursive call.

```
Fixpoint get_number (l:lstest) (H: has_true l) : nat.
  refine (
      match l as l' return l' = _ -> nat with
      | (true, n)::_ => fun L => n
      | (false, _)::l' => fun L => get_number l' _
      | [] => fun L => _
      end eq_refl).

  now exfalso; subst l; inversion H.

  now subst l; inversion H; inversion H0;
    [congruence |  eexists; eauto].

Defined.
```

The function uses the *convoy pattern* so that the `match` statement does not forget the shape of `l` in the different branches.

If you want to, you can prove rewriting lemmas to make it easier to use.

```
Lemma get_number_false l m H: exists H', get_number ((false, m)::l) H = get_number l H'.
Proof. eexists; reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma get_number_true l m H: get_number ((true, m)::l) H = m.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma get_number_nil H m: get_number [] H <> m.
Proof.  now inversion H. Qed.

Lemma get_number_proof_irrel l H1 H2: get_number l H1 = get_number l H2.
Proof. induction l as [ | [[|] ?] l']; eauto; now inversion H1. Qed.
```